# Are build config keys obfuscated by ProGuard?

Tags: android, build.gradle, proguard

Is the build config `key` declared in the `build.gradle` file obfuscated by ProGuard using `proguard-android.txt`?

For example:

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            buildConfigField "String", "key", "\"value\""
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If you have minifyEnabled and shrinkResources set to true and not excluded in the proguard rules file, which you should add to your question.